# JavaScript not reloading with jquery ajax form even if in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code for show more/less of my comment with toggle. It works great. However I have another form for adding comments and that form is using jQuery ajax. So after adding a form the script is not working. I have to reload the whole page to show it working correctly. In the source I see the script loaded. It is also in side the part that is reloading.

Maybe I should change ready to load?

**EDIT:** onload is not helping either ;(

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $(".comment p").each(function() {
            var val = $.trim(this.innerHTML);
            var parsed = val.split(/\s+/);
            var cut = parsed;

            // for each word
            for (var i = 0, k = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
                k += parsed[i].length + 1;

                if (k - 1 > 50) {
                    cut = parsed.slice(0, i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if one long word
            if (cut.length == 0) {
                cut.push(parsed[0].substring(0, 50));
            }

            val = cut.join(" ");

            // if the text is long enough to cut
            if (cut.length != parsed.length) {
                this.innerHTML = val.replace(/[.,;?!]$/, "")
                    + "<span>...</span> ";

                $("<span />")
                    .css("display", "none")
                    .html(parsed.slice(cut.length).join(" ") + " ")
                    .appendTo(this);

                $("<a />", {
                    href : "#",
                    text : "[show more]"
                }).on("click", function(e) {
                    var sh = this.innerHTML == "[show more]";
                    $(this).prev("span").toggle(sh).prev("span").toggle(!sh);
                    this.innerHTML = sh ? "[show less]" : "[show more]";
                    e.preventDefault();
                }).appendTo(this);
            } else {
                this.innerHTML = val;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** My ajax call looks like this (I am using CodeIgniter):

```
$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo site_url('comments/add'); ?>",
    type : 'POST',
    data : form_data,
    success : function(msg) {
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        $('.comments-tbl-div').load(pathname + ' .comments-tbl-div');
        $('#comment-form-part').html(msg);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the ready event is fired just one time (at load of document). The ajax engine fire the success event after ready document. So you should re-call your showMore engine.

First, put your code in a callable function

```
<script>
        function showMoreEngine($els) {
            $els.each(function() {
            var val = $.trim(this.innerHTML),
                parsed = val.split(/\s+/),
                cut = parsed;

            // for each word
            for (var i = 0, k = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
                k += parsed[i].length + 1;

                if (k - 1 > 50) {
                    cut = parsed.slice(0, i);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // if one long word
            if (cut.length == 0) {
                cut.push(parsed[0].substring(0, 50));
            }

            val = cut.join(" ");

            // if the text is long enough to cut
            if (cut.length != parsed.length) {
                this.innerHTML = val.replace(/[.,;?!]$/, "")
                    + "<span>...</span> ";

                $("<span />")
                    .css("display", "none")
                    .html(parsed.slice(cut.length).join(" ") + " ")
                    .appendTo(this);

                $("<a />", {
                    href : "#",
                    text : "[show more]"
                }).on("click", function(e) {
                    var sh = this.innerHTML == "[show more]";
                    $(this).prev("span").toggle(sh).prev("span").toggle(!sh);
                    this.innerHTML = sh ? "[show less]" : "[show more]";
                    e.preventDefault();
                }).appendTo(this);
            } else {
                this.innerHTML = val;
            }
        });
        }
</script>
```

call this function at ready event

```
   $(document).ready(function(e) { showMoreEngine($(".comment p"))});
```

and in your ajax engine

```
 $.ajax({
        url : "<?php echo site_url('comments/add'); ?>",
        type : 'POST',
        data : form_data,
        success : function(msg)
                  {
                        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
                        // added here a callback function
                        $('.comments-tbl-div').load(pathname + ' .comments-tbl-div',{},function() {showMoreEngine( $(this).find('.comment p') )});
                        $('#comment-form-part').html(msg);
                        showMoreEngine( $('#comment-form-part').find('.comment p') );
                    }
                });
```

I think that you can optimize the code... but this can be a point of start.

Comment: Hmm, I tried it and I still need to reload the page. I think it has something to do with asynchronous behaviour of AJAX. So, I think I need to trigger showMoreEngine after $('.comments-tbl-div').load(pathname + ' .comments-tbl-div'); ...... Right now I think it is performing showMoreEngine before reloading the content, eventhough it is later in code. Can you suggest some techinque how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes i've note seen the div load sorry. I've not now the DOC. But you should see how call the function after your last ajax call

Comment: I don't understand your `$('.comments-tbl-div').load(pathname + ' .comments-tbl-div');`. This is not a url. What is this?

Comment: It is part of a page that is reloaded, not the entire page.

Comment: I think I woll start a bounty I need to solve this problem with not reloading when using ajax.

Comment: @Derfder I modified the last part... I've added the callback function as 3th parameter. (http://api.jquery.com/load/). Try now

Comment: No, still I need a refresh after submit to see changes. I still think the problem is that showMoreEngine is executed before $('.comments-tbl-div').load(pathname + ' .comments-tbl-div',{},function() {$(this).find('.comment p')}); because of JavaScript asynchronous behaviur. I need somehow force showMoreEngine function to load after other code. How to achieve that?

Comment: @Derfder Sorry! I missed the ShowMoreEngine function in 3th param. Try now please.